# acceder a un path de un dominio diferente

Tags: c#, rutas

Buen día, estoy trabajando con DBF's y me surgió un problema. mi conexión actualmete la hago de la siguiente manera:

```
OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB; Data Source=\\ServidorPrincipal\dbf; Extended Properties=dBase III");
```

Tanto en pruebas locales como en servidor de pruebas estaba funcionando al 100%, sin problemas. Cuando llegó al servidor de producción me empezó a marcar que el path no existe. después de investigar un poco, el servidor de producción no está dentro del mismo dominio que mi ambiente local y de pruebas, por lo cuál no tengo acceso al path. ya tengo credenciales de acceso, pero no sé en qué parte debo de ponerlas para acceder a dicho dominio, he leído en internet pero no he encontrado algo que solucione mi problema. ¿Alguna idea?
Todo esto es en servidores de windows, por si hacía falta aclararlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, quieres hacer funcionar tu aplicación en un entorno de pruebas pero accediendo a la base de datos de producción, que no está en el mismo dominio.

La base de datos está en la carpeta compartida del servidor `\\ServidorPrincipal\dbf`.

Debes ir al servidor, con privilegios suficientes, editar las propiedades de esta carpeta compartida y asignarle los permisos de lectura/escritura al usuario de la aplicación (nombre de dominio).